# How to tune the hyperparameters of XGBoost and RF?

Tags: python, random-forest, xgboost, hyperparameter-tuning, bayesian-networks

How to tune the hyperparameters of XGBoost and RF in python?

There are several methods to tune hyperparameteres of XGBoost and RF such as Bayesian Optimization and meta learning and gridseachcv?
Which one is prefer in which cases?

How Bayesian optimization work for hyperparameteres tuning?

Comment: Why not girdsearchcv?

Comment: We can add this also to list! I would like to know more about Bayesian optimization in comparison to others!